# No javap tool not found in Scala REPL

Tags: scala, read-eval-print-loop, javap

I am using Scala 2.11.6 (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.7.0_79) on Windows 10.

I did following in REPL

```
scala> class Book (val title:String)
defined class Book
scala> :javap
:javap [-lcsvp] [path1 path2 ...]
scala> :javap -c Book
Failed: No javap tool available: scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.JavapClass$JavapTool6 failed to initialize.
```

My PATH environment variable has C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_79\bin and JAVA_HOME is set to C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_79

I can see the javap.exe in C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_79\bin.

Am I missing something?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

scala> :javap -c Book
Failed: No javap tool available: scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.JavapClass$**JavapTool6** failed to initialize.

You used JDK 7 but the error message said failed to initialize JavapTool6 not JavapTool7

JavapTool6 and JavapTool7 are different in source: [JavapClass.scala](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/2.11.x/src/repl/scala/tools/nsc/interpreter/JavapClass.scala)

Maybe you activate scala REPL with JDK6