# I am trying javap -p classname on scala class but getting error in REPL

Tags: scala, read-eval-print-loop, javap, scala-repl

```
scala> class Department( val departmentId: Int, val departmentName: String)
defined class Department
scala> javap -p Department
<console>:12: error: not found: value javap
       javap -p Department
       ^
<console>:12: error: not found: value p
       javap -p Department
              ^
```

Comment: What you are trying to do does not make any sense. Scala REPL evaluates pieces of scala code, it does not know anything about `javap` or any other external commands available on the usual command line. You can invoke shell commands with `:sh`, but it won't help here either, because the REPL does not produce any files like `Department.class` while compiling the input, it keeps the representation of the `Department` class in memory. You can use the `:javap` REPL command, though.

Comment: Thanks for quick response!!  I am thinking that the class Department is compiled and when i will use javap then it should show the class information.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot invoke `javap` program as if you are in the normal shell, because the Scala REPL is *not* a shell.

You can use the built-in command `:javap` though:

```
scala> class Department( val departmentId: Int, val departmentName: String)
defined class Department

scala> :javap -p Department
Compiled from "<console>"
public class $line4.$read$$iw$$iw$Department {
  private final int departmentId;
  private final java.lang.String departmentName;
  public int departmentId();
  public java.lang.String departmentName();
  public $line4.$read$$iw$$iw$Department(int, java.lang.String);
}
```

From the REPL `:help`:

> `:javap <path|class>`      disassemble a file or class name

Comment: Now getting another error. Failed: No javap tool available: scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.JavapClass$JavapTool6 failed to initialize.

Comment: @MayankKishore Check the java versions then. Could it be that you are using some very old scala interpreter? [Question with very similar error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39629223/no-javap-tool-not-found-in-scala-repl?rq=1).